# Erlang, Matching with list foreach

Tags: erlang

I've been making a chat application in Erlang for a school project, but I've run into an issue. I'm trying to make my program concurrent and in order to do so I start a new thread for each message a channel is sending. I do this using lists:foreach, but I want to make sure that I don't message the person who typed in the channel.

```
request(State, {message, {UserID,UserPID}, Token}) ->
case catch lists:member({UserID,UserPID}, State#channel.users) of
    false ->
        {{error, user_not_joined}, State};
    true -> 
        spawn( fun() ->
        ListOfUsers = State#channel.users,
        UserPIDs = lists:map(fun ({_, V}) -> V end, ListOfUsers),
        %spawn( fun() ->end)
        lists:foreach( 
            fun(UserPID) -> ok end,
            fun(PID) ->
                spawn( fun() -> genserver:request(PID, {message_from_server, State#channel.name, UserID, Token}) end) 
            end, UserPIDs) end),
        {ok, State}
end;
```

What I pretty much want to do is to match with the UserPID inside the foreach. As of now I only get warnings:

channel.erl:39: Warning: variable 'UserPID' is unused
channel.erl:39: Warning: variable 'UserPID' shadowed in 'fun'

Line 3 is fun(UserPID) -> ok end,

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

The answer by legoscia is fine, but I'd add that often list comprehension is simpler to use and simpler to read than `lists:foreach`. Note that list comprehension is able to ignore values based on clauses. Consider the following example:

```
-module(filter).

-export([do/0]).

do() ->
    Values = lists:seq(1,10),
    IgnoreThisValue = 5,
    %% print all values unequal to IgnoreThisValue
    [io:format("Value: ~b~n", [Value]) ||
     Value <- Values, Value =/= IgnoreThisValue],
    ok.
```

Run it in the shell:

```
1> make:all([load]).
Recompile: filter
up_to_date
2> filter:do().     
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
Value: 6
Value: 7
Value: 8
Value: 9
Value: 10
```

A side note on your code: Why do you spawn a thread per process? I assume that you are using the behaviour `gen_server` (correct me if I am wrong). If so, you should consider using the `cast` function to simply send a message. As you do not check the result of `genserver:request/2`, this might be a viable option which saves you a lot of processes.

Comment: Another way, which is slower, is to use `L -- [Pid]` to excise the Pid from the list before traversing it. But this builds a new list.

Answer (score 4):

Since the function argument shadows the existing variable, you need to use a guard for that:

```
fun(PID) when PID =:= UserPID -> ok end
```